Cannot get a callback from the FlutterBluePlus().turnOn(); method
I cannot get a callback from FlutterBluePlus().turnOn();
This is my function:
  void checkIfBluetoothOn() async {
    bool isBluetoothOn = await flutterBlue.turnOn();
    if(isBluetoothOn){
      print("Bluetooth is On");
    }
  }

I want to get a callback when the user denies or allow the bluetooth to turn on. currently when the dialogue box shows it returns true and does not return false when the user denies to turn the bluetooth on.
picture of the code

I checked the docs, it's not even returning a Future, it's returning a Future. How did you get the true value?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

when i print the isBluetoothOn it prints TRUE even when i reject to Turn on Bluetooth. I want when i run this function and it asks the user to allow or deny to turn the bluetooth on it should return false if the user denies and true if the user allows.
I have added a picture in the question please check that out

@DhafinRayhan . can u help?

@GAMEMODIFIER109 Before that, please check the breaking changes first.

@DhafinRayhan yeah it was the issue with me i was using the older version now when i have updated the package it throws error when a user denies to turn the bluetooth on. Thanks.

I got the answer. i was not using the latest version of flutter blue plus in the latest version we can wrap our logic with the try catch and if the user denies to turn the Bluetooth on it throws an error which it was not throwing before.
